# Turning digits in an array to an integer. (and more)

Tags: c, arrays, digits

Im new to C and trying to build a program thats uses only:

- arrays,
- loops,
- if-else,
- basic functions (print, scan)
- no strings and such!

My requirements:

- I should get an equation from user in one line. '=' ends the equation.
- There must be exactly two numbers
- There must be exactly one operator

Example input:

```
589*919=
```

I need to insert the equation into an array. Each digit or operator sits at another place in the array.

Array example:

```
chars array: | 5 | 8 | 9 | * | 9 | 1 | 9 |
```

I then need to turn the digits in the array into two integers, and calculate the answer of the equation.

How can I turn the digits in the array into two integers?

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)
#define SIZE 122

void main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    char input;
    char equation[SIZE];
    char key = 0;
    int oprIndex;

    printf("Insert equation:\n");
    scanf("%c", &input);

    for (i = 0; i<SIZE && input != '='; i++) //fill the array with the equation
    {
        equation[i] = input;
        scanf("%c", &input);
        count++;
    }

    //searching for which operater user inserted
    key = '+';
    for (i = 0; i < count && equation[i] != key; i++);
    if (equation[i] == key)
    {
        printf("key: %c\n", key);
        oprIndex = i;
        printf("index: %d\n", oprIndex);
    }

    key = '-';
    for (i = 0; i < count && equation[i] != key; i++);
    if (equation[i] == key)
    {
        printf("key: %c\n", key);
        oprIndex = i;
        printf("index: %d\n", oprIndex);
    }

    key = '*';
    for (i = 0; i < count && equation[i] != key; i++);
    if (equation[i] == key)
    {
        printf("key: %c\n", key);
        oprIndex = i;
        printf("index: %d\n", oprIndex);
    }

    key = '/';
    for (i = 0; i < count && equation[i] != key; i++);
    if (equation[i] == key)
    {
        printf("key: %c\n", key);
        oprIndex = i;
        printf("index: %d\n", oprIndex);
    }
    //end of searching

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) //print the equation
    {
        printf("%c", equation[i]);
    }
    printf("=");
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Code only allows 1 character in `input`.  It that intended?  Suggest `char input[100]; fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);`  Too bad "uses only: ... (print, scan)" may not allow that.

Comment: yea I didnt learn this functions yet.. but it will come soon ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use for statement with `+` and `*`.

If what you don't know is the way to convert character to corresponding number, then use `-'0'`.

For example, `'5'-'0'` will gives you `5`, integer value.

Edit:

I add some example for you.

```
int main(void) // use return value of int, not void
{
    ... // After you get oprIndex.

    // Declare
    // int opA, opB;
    // first.

    opA = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < oprIndex; i++)
    {
        opA *= 10;
        opA += equation[i] - '0';
    }

    opB = 0;
    for (i = oprIndex + 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        opB *= 10;
        opB += equation[i] - '0';
    }

    ... // Do calcuation.

    return 0; // Use return 0; at the last line of the main function.
              // For C++, this is added implicitly,
              // but in C, implicit adding is not in standard.
}
```

However, in your code, there are several semantic bugs
(for example,

```
key = '+';
for (i = 0; i < count && equation[i] != key; i++);
if (equation[i] == key)
```

makes an segmentation fault when your `count` equals to `SIZE` and there is no `+` in the equation.),
so refactor your logic and code for right execution.

Comment: And you might want to multiply by 10 after each iteration, but not the first until you find the operator. This might convert the number easily.

Comment: still didnt get it.. for example: i should look for the index of '+' in the array, and than get each digit before the '+' and add it to a new variable bt *10 and +digit?

Comment: damn.. its so hard work, and i dont sure if i would do it right, can u show me example of the for loop just once? so i will have an guideline. please ;)

Comment: @MichaelAstahov I add some example.

Comment: Thanks you. the program is running and working :).  yea when there is no operator in the equation, the counter will go highr than the array size, in this specific program i can assume that the equation inserted right.

Comment: @MichaelAstahov No. you must check whether `i == count` before checking value of `equation[i]`.